# Can System.Diagnostic redirect output when any string is received and not at the end of line?

Tags: .net, process

Is it possible to receive the output from System.Diagnostic.Process when..occur and not at the end of line ?
At the moment, i have

```
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;

    reg = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);

    reg.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
    reg.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

As you can see, a call to BeginOutputReadLine allow me to read the (redirected) output **only when an end line is found**. 
Does exists the same method but that call the delegate "when the process send any char to output" ?

Thanks

Comment: There must be. isnt there any beginread or read method?

Comment: This is entirely up to the process you redirect.  Most C runtime implementations switch to buffered mode when output is redirected.  Which doesn't flush output until "\n" is written or the buffer is full, whichever comes first.  Nothing you can do about it if you don't have the source of that program.

Comment: @HansPassant : i know the main application (timidity) flush the output when is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that the asynchronous methods/events don't allow you to read single characters from the output (Only complete lines, as the method names suggest).

The following code does what you want, but in a synchronous way:

```
class Program
{
    public static bool Exit = false;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Process
                    {
                        StartInfo =
                            {
                                FileName = @"program-not-outputting-newlines",
                                Arguments = "test",
                                UseShellExecute = false,
                                RedirectStandardOutput = true
                            },
                        EnableRaisingEvents = true
                    };
        p.Start();
        var s = p.StandardOutput;
        p.Exited += (sender, e) => Exit = true;

        while(!Exit)
        {
            Console.Write((char) s.Read());
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The call to s.Read() seems to block the current thread (Even though there is a ReadBlock() version of it -- the docwriter probably misunderstood), so you might want to make that in a seperate thread and do some message passing/eventraising of your own to make it asynchronous.

The program I tested with was a simple loop outputting integers from 0 to 10 with random intervals, without newlines in between, and calls to Console.Out.Flush for every write.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no, there are is such method on **Process** that does what you need.

Long answer: yes, you do appear to be able to do this, but it will take you a lot more work.

(Still, as Hans Passant says, it's also up to the other process to flush early. If it doesn't, nothing is going to help you.)

**Method 1 (hard)**

**BeginOutputReadLine** appears to create a synchronized wrapper around the actual underlying **Stream.BeginRead** method, ensuring it buffers enough data and calls your **OutputDataReceived** handler. (And it actually does quite a bit of work to give you complete lines, not chunks, not to mention the synchronized event dispatching, from what I can see with ILSpy.)

So you might try to call the **StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead** method directly, skipping **OutputDataReceived** and **BeginOutputReadLine** entirely, so you can receive the chunks as they are received.

Unfortunately, that does mean that you need to do the encoding yourself (as Streams deal with bytes not chars, but the **StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding** provides the bulk of this support), you'll need to do all the async reading yourself (**Stream.BeginRead** is not a pleasant API to work against), and you'll need to handle the synchronizing yourself.

Lots of fun (and lots of chances to get something wrong).

**Method 2 (easier), almost async**

You can also read from the **StandardOutput** synchronously using **StandardOutput.Read**.  If you do not want to block, you could spin off another thread or use **TaskFactory.StartNew**:

```
var readTask = TaskFactory.StartNew(() => {
    try
    {
        while ((int c = process.StandardOutput.Read()) != -1) 
        {
           ...
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // don't want to kill the process if something goes wrong above;
        // uncaught exceptions on background threads do that.
    }
});
```

And then at the point you want to be sure the reading is done, you say

```
readTask.Wait();
```